# Page not found(404) error if reset password email link is wrong in django

Tags: python, django, forgot-password

I am using django default password reset feature.I get the set new password email link via email.

If the url is correct then it's fine. Now if I put a wrong or invalid link then I get,

```
The current URL, account/reset/NTQ/4ox-7f135b9b74e7a4aa909fdd/, didn't match any of these.
```

accounts/urls.py --

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
#url(r'^reset/',auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='empty_password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Template password_reset_confirm.html --

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% if validlink %}
    <h3>Change password</h3>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Change password</button>
    </form>
  {% else %}
    <p>
      The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.
      Please request a new password reset.
    </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I tried with --

```
url(r'^reset/',auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='empty_password_reset_confirm')
```

But in that case I am getting `AssertionError at /account/reset/NTQ/4ox-7f135b9b74e7a4aa909fdd/`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have described the current intended behavior. But what do you want to have instead?

Comment: If the url is wrong it should not show 404 error. Instead it should show the `else` part of `password_reset_confirm.html` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the regex of the url to make it work for like every url

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

For the example link you mentioned the above will work. You can modify the regex in the same way for more cases according to your requirements.

When your url goes to the link with wrong token it will throw the error thus your else part of template will show up.

Comment: Brilliant. It worked. But I have no clue why it is {1,20} not {1,23}. This is the only change I can see.

Comment: they have to set it to something that's all. You can modify as you like.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more, I don't understand how did this work. You said have can modify as you like but how do I know what modification is needed in order to match the pattern.